# Javascript scroll to bottom doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this script:

```
<?php
header("refresh: 5;");
include 'theme.php';
ceklogin();
css();
echo <<<HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
var textarea = document.getElementById(\"wget\");
textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
</script>
HTML;
echo " Wget log :<br>";
echo "<textarea name=\"text-info\" rows=\"30\" id=\"wget\" cols=\"90\" readonly style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 7pt;\" >";
$datalines = file ("wget.log");
foreach ($datalines as $zz) {
echo $zz; }
echo "</textarea></div>";
foot();
echo '

</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

the javascript part doesn't work, it won't scrool to bottom on the textarea every time it refreshes the page, any ideas?

**Update: I modified my script to be like this but still doesn't work**

```
<?php
header("refresh: 5;");
include 'theme.php';
ceklogin();
css();
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       var textarea = document.getElementById(\"wget\");
       textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
      </script>';
echo " Wget log :<br>";
echo "<textarea name=\"text-info\" rows=\"30\" id=\"wget\" cols=\"90\" readonly style=\"font-family: Arial;font-size: 7pt;\" >";
$file = file_get_contents('/www/wget.log');
echo $file;
echo "</textarea></div>";
foot();
echo '

</div>
</body>
</div>
</html>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
       var textarea = document.getElementById(\"wget\");
       textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
      </script>';
```

(Removed the `<<<HTML` and reformatted the HTML string.)

Comment: I was just going to say that I put the basic code into a fiddle and the Javascript works ... **http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/shc9tmbk/**, so the issue is in the PHP, not the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving your Javascript to the bottom of the body and putting this in a function:

```
(function() {
   var textarea = document.getElementById(\"wget\");
   textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
})();
```